# Finding dimension and subspace in $\mathbb{R}^5$ with only two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, hamel-basis

> Let $v=(1,1,1,0,0)$ and $w=(1,0,0,-1,-1)$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$. Find a basis and the dimension for the subspace $S=\{u \in \mathbb{R}^5 \mid u \cdot v=0 \text{ and } u\cdot w = 0\}$.

I tried putting them into a matrix and reducing, but I have no idea where to go from there. It is an assignment question, so I'm not asking for the answer, just and idea of how to solve it, because I have nothing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "I tried putting them into a matrix and reducing"?  Are $u,v$ the rows or the columns of this matrix?  Is there a particular reason you started row-reducing, or was it just because every linear algebra problem so far involves row reducing at some point?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I row reduced to find the rank of the matrix, and how many parameters it had, which ended up being three. Then I expressed the leading columns by those parameters, and separating them into their basis vectors. I took the number of basis vectors to be the dimension of the subspace, which I'm not quite sure of.

Comment: What are you finding a basis **of**, exactly? Are you finding a basis of the solution space (that is, the nullspace of my matrix below)?  It does *sound* like you're doing the right thing and yes the dimension should be $3$, but it would be easier for us to communicate and easier for you to do these problems if you could learn to explain **why** you're doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If you write out the equations that define $S$, you'll see that $u = (u_1,\dots,u_5)$ is an element of $S$ exactly when it is a solution to the system
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&-1&-1
} \mathbf{u} = \pmatrix{0\\0}
$$